# Fogbugz API - formatting data submitted into the sEvent field

Tags: xml, api, fogbugz

I'm using the Fogbugz API (v6.0) to submit new cases from some error reporting code.

I can't find the correct syntax to put line breaks in the case description field.

sample api call:

```
http://fogbugz.somesite.com/api.asp?token=b99n6u07v8qrsoqq4710ukogff5u18&cmd=new&sTitle=www.somesite.com|/ajaxRTF.asp|Permission denied&ixProject=209&ixArea=&sEvent=500 Page Error<linebreak>www.somesite.com<linebreak>Error Generated: 0x800A0046 Microsoft VBScript runtime /ajaxRTF.asp 582 -1 Permission denied&fScoutStopReporting=1&sPersonAssignedTo=Andrew Davies&sScoutDescription=www%2Ei%2Dleeds%2Enet%7C%2FajaxRTF%2Easp%7CPermission+denied
```

I want to have line breaks where `<linebreak>` is in the above code. So that when the case in viewed in FB browser it's properly formatted

e.g.

500 Page Error

www.somesite.com

Error Generated: 0x800A0046 Microsoft VBScript runtime /ajaxRTF.asp 582 -1 Permission denied

Thanks in advance,

Andy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

%0A represents the newline character URL encoded.

%0D%0A is carriage return/line feed, but the %0D is not necessary.